# Create a GTK+ Cellrenderer with cairo

Tags: gtk, vala

This has now bugged me for at least a few days(and, sadly, nights). I wanna write a rather easy cellrenderer in Gtk+. Since I'm only drawing text(plus the additions with cairo), I'm subclassing from Gtk.CellRendererText(it's Vala+Gtk3 btw).
I've made a minimal example here:

```
class CellRendererTest : CellRendererText{
public override void render (Cairo.Context ctx, Widget tree,
            Gdk.Rectangle background_area, Gdk.Rectangle cell_area,
            CellRendererState flags) {

        base.render (ctx, tree, background_area, cell_area, flags);
        ctx.rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        ctx.fill();

    }
}


class Test : Window{
    public Test(){
        TreeStore store = new TreeStore(1, typeof(string));
        TreeView tv = new TreeView.with_model(store);
        tv.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Foo",
        new CellRendererTest(), "text", 0);


        TreeIter iter;
        store.append (out iter, null);
        store.set (iter, 0, "first", -1);
        store.append(out iter, null);
        store.set (iter, 0, "second", -1);
        store.append (out iter, null);
        store.set (iter, 0, "third", -1);

        add(tv);
        this.show_all();
    }

    static void main(string[] args){
        Gtk.init(ref args);
        new Test();
        Gtk.main();
    }
}
```

So I thought this would give every entry in the treeview a black box at the upper left corner, but in fact it only draws the box once. This exampe doesn't make this clear, but it's also not possible that the box gets drawn at the same position three times(I've tried that with some different code).

So, does anyone know how to achieve the desired effect here?

Comment: where do x and y come from in the render method?

Comment: Woops, they are leftovers from a test(and should just be 0), I'll remove them.

Comment: I've not done any cell rendering but I'm pretty sure you need to do all of your drawing within background_area. See https://live.gnome.org/Vala/GtkCellRendererSample

Comment: Exactly, I needed to use background_area.x/y instead of 0/0 here and it disappeared because of the clipping gtk does. Thanks.